# setting a format for a date in ms access

Tags: java, sql, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to format a date formatted result from a database into date only. ("dd"). The query results are formatted like this, `2014-05-17 00:00:00` I want to extract only "17", How can I achieved this? This is my code.

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT date FROM Attendance;";
            Object[][] queryResult = connectToDB(headerQuery);

            for(int x = 0; x < queryResult.length; x++){
                for(int y=0; y < queryResult[x].length; y++){
                    Object temp = queryResult[x][y];
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
                    System.out.print(format.format(temp));
                    System.out.println(temp+ "<-----");
                }
                System.out.println("---");
            }
```

this is my error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

UPDATE: I've changed the for-loop into this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < queryResult.length; x++){
                for(int y=0; y < queryResult[x].length; y++){
                    String temp = (queryResult[x][y]).toString();
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
                    Date date = (Date) format.parse(temp);

                    System.out.println(date+ "<-----");
                }
                System.out.println("---");
            }
```

but it still does not format the date;

Comment: It seems that `Object temp = headerQueryResult[x][y];` is of type `String`. What is the output of `System.out.println(temp+ "<-----");
`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so you're trying to format a String.  That is, `temp` is a String and you can't pass that into `format`.  You need to turn that String into a Date then pass it into `format`.  [Here's how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

But, even better, you should be returning a `Date` from the query instead of a `String`.  That'll make your life much easier. Then you don't need to change any other part of the code.

Show us your `connectToDB`.  Assuming it's using JDBC, you should get the result by calling [ResultSet.getDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @user3615601 that won't change anything.  You just casted the result, you need to *change* the input to `format`, not the output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SQL to extract the day part?

```
SELECT DatePart('d', [date]) as theDay FROM Attendance
```